# Minimum number of Alternating 1 and 0

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to find the minimum number of flips required to get an alternating of [0, 1, 0, 1] for example given [1, 1, 0, 1]. so in this case, it is one flip.

```
def solution(A):
    count = 0
    myDict = {}
    myDict[1] = True
    myDict[0] = False

    next = None
    # first element value
    val = myDict[A[0]]
    if val == True:
        next = False
    else:
        next = True

    for element in A[1:]:
        if next != myDict[element]:
            count += 1
            # do something to update element
            myDict[element] = next
        if myDict[element] == True:
            next = False
        else:
            next = True

    return count
```

My solution does not work for the input [1, 1, 0, 1, 1]. Because it gives back 3 when the answer it should give back is 2(change the first index and last index elements to 0). How can i solve this?

Comment: Can it be [1, 0, 1, 0 ]  too or only [0, 1, 0, 1] ??

Comment: both are acceptable

Answer (score 4):

You could just count the differences for each kind of pattern and take the `min`

```
def minFlip(a):
    return min(
        sum(n == i % 2 for i, n in enumerate(a)),
        sum(n == (i + 1) % 2 for i, n in enumerate(a))
    )

minFlip([1, 1, 0, 1, 1])
#2
minFlip([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
#0
minFlip([1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
#2
minFlip([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
#2
```

Answer (score 3):

You could count the values for which the least significant bit is different from that of the index. Then take that count or the "opposite" (len-count):

```
def minFlip(a):
    flips = sum((n ^ i) & 1 for i, n in enumerate(a))
    return min(flips, len(a)-flips)
```

Alternatively, you could sum up 1 and -1 depending on that bit, and then derive the solution from that:

```
def minFlip(a):
    return (len(a)-abs(sum(-1 if (n^i)&1 else 1 for i,n in enumerate(a)))) // 2
```

Comment: Every part of this has been somewhere in some previous answer, but not as succinctly.

Comment: Added an alternative which was not mentioned yet.

Answer (score 2):

(The number of flips to achieve an alternating pattern starting with 0) + (the number of flips to achieve an alternating pattern starting with 1) = (n: the number of elements in your list)

So:

1. Find out how many flips it would take to achieve an alternating pattern starting with 0.  Call this `patt0`.
2. `patt1 = n - patt0`
3. `ans = min(patt0, patt1)`

So in your case, you found it took 3 flips for a list of 5, so `ans = min(3, 5-3)` which is `2`.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here's an `O(1)` space basic dynamic programming, not much different than other proposed solutions, but can be seen [here](https://ideone.com/fDXI75) to start outrunning the ones that use list comprehensions.

```py
def f(A):
  a, b = 0, 0
  for i in xrange(len(A)):
    m = i & 1 ^ A[i]
    a, b = m + a, (not m) + b
  return min(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

solution:

- pattern in the form of 0,1; this can be set in the pattern
- loop input_values
- if is 1,3,5.. (odd element)

  - if value is not false then add 1 to flips
- if is 2,4,6 (even element)

  - if value is not true then add 1 to flips
- return flips

```
def getFlips(input_value):
  pattern = [False, True]
  flips = 0
  for i in range(len(input_value)):
    if i % 2 == 1:
      flips += (1 if input_value[i] != pattern[0] else 0)
    elif i % 2 == 0:
      flips += (1 if input_value[i] != pattern[1] else 0)
  return flips
```

example:

```
print(getFlips([True, True, True, False])) == 1
```

Comment: What if `[False, True, False, True]` needs less flips?

Comment: Your example returns 3, but clearly just flipping the first bit makes the patter correct in one flip.

Comment: @greybeard try the example code. ```getFlips([False, True, False, True])``` returns `4`

Comment: match is what the output should be flipped to, then input_value is the value you want to know how many flips it needs to match the match values array

Comment: ```[False, True, False, True]``` would require 4 flips

Comment: ```[True, False, True, False]``` would require 0 flips

Comment: Why does `[False, True, False, True]` require four flips to get an alternating pattern? It's already an alternating pattern.

Comment: alternating? oh, the way you posed the question, it seems you wanted it to match a pre defined pattern. please wait, will post new answer

Comment: is you pattern of `0, 1` or `1, 0`

Comment: It's not my question, but to me it sound like they want and alternating pattern -- *either* `1, 0` or `0, 1`.

Comment: so given an array input of 1 and 0, the resulting array should just be alternating (eg 1, 0, 1, 0 or 0, 1, 0, 1 etc)

Comment: So you have now changed your requirements after having received correct answers to the original question @Desmond!

Comment: with edit: `getFlips([True, True, True, False])` --> `3`?

Comment: that was before edit, this is the latest version https://repl.it/repls/UnnaturalExpensiveCrash